# Send email in android without user interaction

Tags: java, android, email, exception

I am trying to create application which sends email without user interaction using 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) solution.

I am getting the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ammad.emailmodule, PID: 2251
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sendEmail(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnSend'
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:307)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:266)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am unable to solve this issue. Can anybody help me to find out what is the issue?

Comment: It seems you have an `onClick` function for your send-button, could you please paste your Layout XML when you define the `btnSend`, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml in sendEmail button add attribute android:onClick="sendEmail".

Answer (score 0):

Your not initialized the button so its shown this then add onclivk listener